# References for $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\binom{1}{t}^3\,\mathrm dt=\frac{3}{2}+\frac{6}{\pi^2}$ and related integrals?

Tags: reference-request, definite-integrals, binomial-coefficients

In user dxdydz's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3513155/53283) to the question "Unexpected appearances of $\pi^{2}/6$", he or she mentions the identity $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\binom{1}{t}^3\,\mathrm dt=\frac{3}{2}+\frac{6}{\pi^2}.$$
I hadn't seen an integral quite like this one before. It turns out Ramanujan did work on it - as dxdydz states, it comes up in both Part 1 (p. 302 - 304) and Part 2 (p. 225-227) of his Notebooks.

I wonder, though, if there are any articles or books that delve into such integrals involving binomial coefficients more elaborately. Do you know any references?

Comment: Well, it *might* help explaining what $\binom{1}{t}$ is supposed to mean... if you really want an answer. If you just want to look as the guy who asked an exotic question (and that's still very popular, here)... go ahead.

Comment: @wasn'tme It's the binomial coefficient with a real argument $t$. I assumed everyone was familiar with this type of notation - not trying to pose or anything. Here's more information on it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Two_real_or_complex_valued_arguments

Comment: I didn't say you're posing, but if you are interested in answers, it might be an idea to make your question self-contained, without any external links, but with all the relevant definitions *inside*.

Answer (score 1):

In general we have that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\dbinom{n}{\alpha x}^{\ell}dx=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\dbinom{n}{\alpha k}^{\ell},\,0<\alpha\leq2/\ell,\,\ell\in\mathbb{N}$$ and you can find a proof of this formula [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/255758/integral-of-power-of-binomials-equal-to-sum-of-power-of-binomials). It is a special case of the following result of Robert Baillie, David Borwein and Jonathan M. Borwein:

> **Theorem**. Assume that $G$ is of bounded variation on $[-\delta,\delta]$, vanishes outside $\left(-\alpha,\alpha\right)$ and it is Lebesgue integrable over $\left(-\alpha,\alpha\right)$ with $0<\alpha<2\pi$ and define its Fourier transform as $$g\left(x\right):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}G\left(u\right)e^{-iux}du.$$ Then $$\lim_{r\rightarrow+\infty}\sum_{k=-r}^{r}g\left(n\right)=\lim_{T\rightarrow+\infty}\int_{-T}^{T}g\left(x\right)dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(G\left(0^{+}\right)+G\left(0^{-}\right)\right)$$

For a reference see [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27642636?seq=1), Proposition $2$. Your particular integral is not covered by the previous theorem but maybe it is possible to adapt the ideas in the article for the sinc function case.